# Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files. ts(8010)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm following a tutorial (link to tutorial below) on setting up an IAP (In-App-Purchase) for a react native app. While writing the code, vs code is warning me that "Type Annotations can only be used in TypeScript files", this warned under the "purchase: InAppPurchase | SubscriptionPurchase" and "error: PurchaseError" part of the code. When looking into this, the most popular solution I could find (on Stack Overflow or elswhere) was to simply disable the 'TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features'.

I don't feel like that solves the problem, but I'm not sure. Would disabling this solve the problem and let my app run as expected? Or is there is another way to include this typescript syntax in my javascript file?

```
    useEffect(() => {
    purchaseUpdateSubscription = RNIap.purchaseUpdatedListener(
        async (purchase: InAppPurchase | SubscriptionPurchase) => {
            const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;

            if (receipt) {
                try {
                    if (Platform.os === 'ios') {
                        RNIap.finishTransactionIOS(purchase.transactionReceipt)
                    }
                    await RNIap.finishTransaction(purchase)
                    await processNewPurchase(purchase)
                } catch (ackErr) {
                    console.log('ackErr', ackErr)
                }
            }
        }
    );

    purchaseErrorSubscription = RNIap.purchaseErrorListener(
        (error: PurchaseError) => {
            console.log('purchaseErrorListener', error)
        }
    );

    return (() => {
        if (purchaseUpdateSubscription) {
            purchaseUpdateSubscription.remove()
            purchaseUpdateSubscription = null;
        }
        if (purchaseErrorSubscription) {
            purchaseErrorSubscription.remove()
            purchaseUpdateSubscription = null;
        }
    })
}, [])
```

link to tutorial: https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-native-subscriptions-with-in-app-purchases-setup-fdaf3863e07f

Comment: The code in tutorial was written in TypeScript. If you want to write plain JavaScript just remove type annotations from your code or set up TypeScript and convert your files into .ts (if your project source is not that big to convert to TS)

Answer (score -1):

If you are compiling the code anyway, you could change the file to a .ts file and put type annotations everywhere (`any` if you don't know or don't want to make a type).